# dead simple chef rvm installation script fails

Tags: rvm, chef-infra

What I have: **Chef**;

What I need: **RVM** installed for `node[:deploy][:user][:name]`. I need user-wide install, not system-wide.

What I tried latest:

```
script 'install_rvm' do
  user = node[:deploy][:user][:name]
  interpreter '/bin/bash'
  code "su -l #{user} -c '\curl https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer | bash -s stable'"
  not_if { ::File.exists? "/home/#{user}/.rvm" }
end
```

When I manually run `su -l <username> -c '\curl <long_url> | bash -s stable'` on test server **surely** it works perfectly.
I expect Chef to run the same code, and in logs it seems like it does, but the next `execute` resource fails because in fact there is no `/home/<username>/.rvm` present.
Yes I know that in Chef I can specify user as `user node[:deploy][:user][:name]` instead of changing user with `su` but for some reason if I do that `rvm` would try to install itself in `/root/.rvm` (env not properly reset?).
Well, I would like to ask, why is Chef so extremely crappy even for such dead-simple tasks, but it looks like I've chosen the wrong place, so *the question is what am I doing wrong or do I miss something obvious*?

Comment: Maybe the issue is with the ``su - `` command. I'm seeing the same discrepancy between chef bash script usage (not working) and manual usage (works fine) when I try to use this command preceding a ``passenger-install-nginx-module`` command.

Comment: what happens if you switch ``user = node[:deploy][:user][:name]`` with  ``user node[:deploy][:user][:name]``, removing the equals sign?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, at least that worked and may be useful if all better ways to do it with Chef fail for you. Here is the resource for installing ruby

```
execute 'install_rvm' do
  user('root')
  user = node[:deploy][:user][:name]
  command "su -l #{user} -c '\curl https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer | bash -s stable'"
  not_if { ::File.exists? "/home/#{user}/.rvm" }
end
```

And the bonus one to create `gemset` if it is not already present:

```
execute 'rvm_install_ruby' do
  user('root')
  user = node[:deploy][:user][:name]
  ruby = node[:deploy][:ruby]
  gemset = node[:deploy][:gemset]
  command "su -l #{user} -c 'rvm use #{ruby}@#{gemset} --install --create'"
  not_if do
    if latest_patchlevel = `rvm list`.scan(/(ruby-#{ruby}-p)(\d+)/).map{ |a| a.last.to_i }.sort.last
      `rvm list gemsets`.match /ruby-#{ruby}-p#{latest_patchlevel}@#{gemset}/
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

why not use [chef-rvm](https://github.com/fnichol/chef-rvm) from [Fletcher Nichol](https://github.com/fnichol) - it is the supported way to deal with [RVM](https://rvm.io) in Chef.

Comment: it fails to install on per-user basis for me, despite more widely-used system install works ok.